# How to assign to a variable the first value of the cursor object in flask pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I am trying to assign to a variable the value of `nr` from the first value of the Cursor object named `items` in my code (which is the max of `nr`) but I don't know how to do that.(I am using flask pymongo. I saw a question similar to mine but it doesn't work for me since I am using a different database).

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/testaree')
def testaree():
    prob = mongo.db.prob
    items = prob.find().sort("nr", pymongo.DESCENDING)
    return flask.jsonify(items)
```

My database `prob` looks like this (I am tring to assign to a variable the value of the biggest `nr` from the db collection):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ae9d062f36d282906c59736"
    },
    "nr": 1,
    "nume": "numeunu",
    "enunt": "-",
    "datedeintrare": "-",
    "datedeiesire": "-"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ae9f190f36d282906c5b461"
    },
    "nr": 2,
    "nume": "numedoi",
    "enunt": "-",
    "datedeintrare": "-",
    "datedeiesire": "-"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit()` so that the database only returns the first result, and access the first element in the list.

```
items = prob.find().sort("nr", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)
return flask.jsonify(items[0])
```

EDIT: You can get the `nr` property as follows. Note that the type of `nr` will depend on the type that is stored in mongo. In your comment you are JSON encoding the int so it will be converted to a string.

```
items = prob.find().sort("nr", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)
nr_prop = items[0]["nr"]
print(nr_prop)
flask.jsonify(nr_prop)
```

Or if `nr` is not an `int` (which it should be from looking at the data in your question) in the database:

```
nr_prop = int(items[0]["nr"])
print(nr_prop)
flask.jsonify(nr_prop)
```

Comment: items[0] gives me the object it but how do I actually get the `nr` like I have in my db collection?

Comment: EDIT: I figgured it out. I did `flask.jsonify(items[0]["nr"])` and than I assign it to a variable `numbers = flask.jsonify(items[0]["nr"])`. But the problem is that my variable is not an integer and I don't know how to make it an integer

Comment: I have updated my answer to include `nr` and data types.

Comment: I tried the same thing to convert it to an `int` but it gives me this error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Please help me. I tried so hard to solve it but I don't know how

Edit: If I `return flask.jsonify(nr_prob)` it does work. But if I `return nr_prob` it gives me the error above

Comment: Have you created a variable called `int`?

Comment: You could also use [find_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one), which is roughly equivalent to what you have here, but will have PyMongo return the first element directly, giving you slightly cleaner code.